# CiviCRM 5.44 WordPress 5.8.2 Initialization Error

Tags: wordpress, installation, 5.44.0

After install of CiviCRM 5.44 on WordPress 5.8.2 I receive the following message:

Initialization Error

Array
(
[callback] => Array
(
[0] => CRM_Core_Error
[1] => simpleHandler
)

```
[code] => -18
[message] => DB Error: no such table
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] => SELECT id, name, value, domain_id, contact_id, is_domain, component_id, created_date, created_id
```

FROM civicrm_setting
WHERE (domain_id = 1) AND (is_domain = 1)
[nativecode=1146 ** Table 'credolvo_WPORV.civicrm_setting' doesn't exist]
[type] => DB_Error
[user_info] => SELECT id, name, value, domain_id, contact_id, is_domain, component_id, created_date, created_id
FROM civicrm_setting
WHERE (domain_id = 1) AND (is_domain = 1)
[nativecode=1146 ** Table 'credolvo_WPORV.civicrm_setting' doesn't exist]
[to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: no such table" code=-18 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::simpleHandler prefix="" info="SELECT id, name, value, domain_id, contact_id, is_domain, component_id, created_date, created_id
FROM civicrm_setting
WHERE (domain_id = 1) AND (is_domain = 1)
[nativecode=1146 ** Table 'credolvo_WPORV.civicrm_setting' doesn't exist]"]
)

When I look at the database, the only civi table is civicrm_address_format.

Other Vital Stats:
Hosting Company: Blue Host
Version 7.4
MySQL Version 5.6.41-84.1

I could really use some help on this.

Comment: can you reference, or spell out, the installation process you followed

Comment: As per instruction on the CiviCRM site, I copied the CiviCRM plugin for  Word Press into the Plugin directory. From WP admin/plugin interface, I activated the plugin. The process began with the Civi activation page, then the errors above presented. To get the site back up, I deleted the CiviCRM plugin folder and the site came back up.

Comment: if you followed every step here https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/wordpress/ then you may want to join https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/wordpress if you haven't already

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the mySQL database version could not support the CiviCRM install version. BLuehost uses 5.6.41-84.1 and 8.0 or better is required.